# How to transfer data of one column of one table to the one column of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: TableA and TableB as given below and I want to transfer data of xyz of Table A to column stu of table B

Table A

```
abc       pqr         xyz

1     apple     1200

2     orange    1500

3     mango     2200
```

---

Table B

```
abc    pqr      stu

1     apple     null

2     orange    null

3     mango     null
```

Comment: It seem that you didn't try to solve your issue yourself. This is a basic request that can be done by a simple query. Why do you waste time to ask a question instead of using some search engine to find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

use join and update

```
update b
set b.stu=a.xyz
from tableB b join 
tableA a on a.abc=b.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

use `update join`

```
update b set stu=xyz
from tableb b inner join tablea
on a.abc=b.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using `merge`:

```
merge TableB as target
using TableA as source
on target.abc = source.abc
when matched then
update stu = source.xyz;
```

presuming `abc` is the primary key for the two tables, otherwise `pqr` needs to be participated in the matching condition too:

```
merge TableB as target
using TableA as source
on target.abc = source.abc and target.pqr = source.pqr
when matched then
update stu = source.xyz;
```